# Laravel Auth Session Missing After Redirect to New Page

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel's Auth to do a login process and keep my application authenticated using username and password in my database. Here is my login function:

```
public function doLogin(Request $req) {
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $req->email, 'password' => $req['password']])) {
        return redirect('/');
    } else {
        return redirect('/login')->with('statusFail', 'true');
    }
}
```

I'm creating my routes like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['login']], function() {
    /*All my authenticated routes here ..*/
}

Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function() {
    /*All my non-authenticated routes here ..*/
}
```

And my middleware like this:

Guest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use Auth;

class GuestMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check())
            return redirect('/');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

LoggedIn:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use Auth;

class LoggedInMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check())
            return redirect('/login');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

At first, I can login using correct username and password, then after surfing some of pages, my auth credentials gone missing and redirected me back to the login back. Sometimes, it only takes 1 website redirection then my auth credentials gone missing.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Are you using the `web` middleware group? This group contains the `StartSession` middleware. Which is required to handle sessions. You can verify that by using `php artisan route:list`, all routes which need the sessions should have the `web` middleware.

Comment: No I'm not, I create a new middleware that handles the Auth thing @DeesOomens

Comment: which version of laravel you are using??

Comment: ver 5.2 @Sohel0415

Comment: @WilliamsPerdana you need to use web middleware, see my answer please

Comment: great ! thanks @Sohel0415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `web` middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
      ///your routes goes here
      Route::group(['middleware' => ['login']], function() {
                 /*All my authenticated routes here ..*/
       });

      Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function() {
           /*All my non-authenticated routes here ..*/
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that typo :

class GuestMiddleware => Name of the both middlewares ?

Rename it and register it accordingly.

Comment: I have registered GuestMiddleware as 'guest' and LoggedInMiddleware as 'login' in my kernel.php file